# Open, Read and Print a 2D Array! (What's wrong with my code?)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fopen, fread, reinterpret-cast

First I reserve some memory using malloc (the file has a [1024][1024] array), after that I open the file using fopen. Then I'm trying to read the file into the reserved memory space. To see if I'm reading it correctly I'm try printing the array but what I get after compiling the code is:
"Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.779 s"
Press any key to continue.

Any suggestions?

```
{

int **A = malloc(sizeof(double[1024][1024]));

FILE *matrizA = fopen("A_1024.dat", "rb");

for(int z = 0; z < 1048576; z++) {
    fread(&A, sizeof(double),1,matrizA);
}

fclose(matrizA);

for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
        printf( "%f ", A[i][j]);
    }
}

free(A);

}
```

Comment: Why fread into &A every time?

Comment: I don't know, I just tought of introducing the values for the array in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration is wrong because the type of the pointer A is invalid.

```
int **A = malloc(sizeof(double[1024][1024]));
```

You have to write

```
double ( *A )[1024] = malloc(sizeof(double[1024][1024]));
```

This loop

```
for(int z = 0; z < 1048576; z++) {
    fread(&A, sizeof(double),1,matrizA);
}
```

is also wrong. You could write

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
    fread( ( double * )A + i, sizeof(double),1,matrizA);
}
```

I assume that the file contains exactly 1048576 doubles. Otherwise you have to check the return value of the call of fread.

Comment: @PabloCorreaChandía There was a typo. See my updated post.

Comment: Thanks! now it's printing something at least but it's full of 0s :(

Comment: @PabloCorreaChandía Check whether the data is indeed written in the binary format and have equal sizes.

Comment: @PabloCorreaChandía In text mode?

Comment: I think so, I have a .txt file with every number ex: 99.888927